# Android アプリで Toast を表示しようとすると落ちる

Tags: android, java

トースト通知を表示させようとすると、以下のようなエラーを出力してアプリが落ちてしまいます。

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.example.test, PID: 4565
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1306)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5290)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:911)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706)
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:86)
    at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:74)
    at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:101)
    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:258)
    at com.example.test.Test.method(Test.java:14)
    at com.example.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6032)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2296)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1306) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5290) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

ソースコード

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Test test = new Test();
    test.methodA();
  }
}

public class Test extends AppCompatActivity{
public void method() {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "text",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); //ここで落ちる
    toast.show();
}
```

API Level は 22 です。
マニフェストファイルには、

```
<activity android:name=".Test"></activity>
```

を追加してあります。
初歩的な質問ではあると思いますが、解決法わかる方いらっしゃいましたら、ご回答よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 解決したら承認という機能で承認してください。[ヘルプ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: @sunsolararrow さん ベストアンサーを追加しました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

どう説明したら良いかわかりませんが、原因はActivityをnewで生成しているためです。

> ```
> Test test = new Test();
> ```

Androidのライフサイクル上でActivityが生成されず、Contextが設定されないまま内部処理で参照してしまい、NullPointerExceptionが発生していると思われます。

### 解決策１

TestクラスがActivityではないのであれば`extends AppCompatActivity`を外して、Activityを継承しないようにすれば問題は発生しないかと思います。
ただし、その場合は`methodA()`にContextを渡す必要があるでしょう。
（Testクラスには`method()`しかありませんが、おそらく`methodA()`の誤記かと思います。）

```java
    Test test = new Test();
    test.methodA(this);
```

```java
public void methodA(Context context) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "text",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
}
```

またその場合は、マニフェストでの`activity`の宣言は不要です。

### 解決策２

TestクラスがActivityの必要があるのであれば、startActivityなどで正しくActivityを起動させてあげてください。
ライフサイクル上でActvityが動作します。

Comment: ありがとうございます！無事に動作しました。Test クラスは Activity ではないため、解決策1 を使用しました。